# How to handle no results in LINQ?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, nullable

in this example code

```
public Company GetCompanyById(Decimal company_id)
{
    IQueryable<Company> cmps = from c in db.Companies
                               where c.active == true && 
                                     c.company_id == company_id
                               select c;
    return cmps.First();
}
```

How should I handle if there is **no data** in `cmps`?

`cmps` **will never be null**, so how can I check for non existing data in a **LINQ Query**?

so I can avoid this

```
'cmps.ToList()' threw an exception of type ... {System.NullReferenceException}
```

when transforming it into, for example, a **List**

```
GetCompanyById(1).ToList();
```

Do I **always need** to wrap it up in a `try catch` block?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Queryable.Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.any.aspx) (or [Enumerable.Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)) to see if there is a member in `cmps`.  This would let you do explicit checking, and handle it however you wish.

If your goal is to just return `null` if there are no matches, just use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) instead of First in your return statement:

```
return cmps.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 5):

What about applying .Any or .Count() ?

Here's an example on MSDN

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
bool hasElements = numbers.Any();
Console.WriteLine("The list {0} empty.",
                    hasElements ? "is not" : "is");
```

Or just use the ?: operator

```
return myExample.Any() ? myExample.First() : null;
```

Answer (score 2):

This will return the first one if there is one, or null if there isn't:

```
return (from c in db.Companies
where c.active == true && 
c.company_id == company_id
select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `return cmps.Count()==0?null:cmp.First()`

That way if it is null it will simply return a null Company and if its not then it will return the first one in the list.

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Comment: Easier to just use FirstOrDefault(), since that's the behavior of FirstOrDefault()...  Also, better to prefer "Any()" to "Count()==0", since Count() will force a full evaluation if there are many elements.

Comment: @Reed Copsey, Just saw your answer about FirstOrDefault() didn't realize thats what it did, definately useful. Your answer is the correct one. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
        var context = new AdventureWorksLT2008Entities();
        var cust = context.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == 1);
        if (cust.Any())
        {
            Customer c = cust.First(); 
        }
```